# Send link with HTML mail body from asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I have an application in which I need to send an email which contains HTML body. Along with that body there should be a link "Click here to confirm your selection". Once user clicks on this link,he/she should be directed to the new page in the new tab from his email.I want to give link of page which is there on localhost. That means when user clicks on link, the page which is there at the link will fire a query that will make entry to my database and appropriate message will be displayed to the user.
Please guide me how can I send link of my page with HTML message body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a [hyperlink](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) (or "anchor tag") in your html - details of how to send an html email can be found [here](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In the mail body add a hyperlink with appropriate querystring (user selection). From that query string you can able to track the selected option by the user and display appropriate message.

For Example http://www.mywebapp.com?useropt=1

Answer (score 1):

create a class :

```
private void SendMail(string To, string Body)
{
    SmtpClient Mailing = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");
    MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();

    Message.From = new MailAddress("mail@domain.com", "Your name or company name");

    Message.Subject = "Subject";
    Message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Message.Body = Body;

    Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));

    Mailing.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    NetworkCredential MyCredential = new NetworkCredential("mail@domain.com", "password");
    Mailing.Credentials = MyCredential;

    Mailing.Send(Message);
}
```

then when you firing the send button pas this code :

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Sendpage.htm"));        
        string body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        body = body.Replace("#NameFamily#", txtNameFamily.Text);
        body = body.Replace("#Email#", txtEmail.Text);
        body = body.Replace("#Tellphone#", txtTellphone.Text);
        body = body.Replace("#Text#", txtText.Text);
        body = body.Replace("#Date#", DateTime.Now);
        string Time = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        body = body.Replace("#Time#", Time);

        SendMail("email that you want to send to it", body);
```

and this is your html body code  :

```
<body>
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
 <table style="height: 193px; width: 549px">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;" class="style4">
                Name Family : [ <span class="style2">#NameFamily#</span> ] 
                <br />
                Email : [ <span class="style2">#Email#</span> ] 
                <br />
                Tell: [ <span class="style2">#Tellphone#</span> ] 
                <br />
                DSC: [ <span class="style2">#Text#</span> ] 
                <br />
                Date: [ <span class="style2">#Date#</span> ] 
                <br />
                Time: [ <span class="style2">#Time#</span> ] 
                <br />
                <br />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="direction: ltr">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```